# Designing a shortest path algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, logic, shortest-path

I have a 5x5 map like this:

[image: map]

```
**C** - is where I am(random)    
**.** - is a passable tile    
**X** - is not a passable tile   
**D** - is destination.
```

My question is how to do an algorithm when I can't pass the tile horizontally or vertically. For example I need to go two tiles up, but I can't pass tile vertically, so I have two options : go left or go right and then go up.

However, one of these might fail, and I would have to go a number of steps back and try another route. I don't know how to do it logically.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community of 4.7 million programmers, just like you, helping each other.

Comment: If you have already an algorithm to find an arbitrary path, adjust it and pass the direction that you came from. Then skip that direction when you probe the directions. For example, if you have just gone north, you can't go north again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand backtracking, Please check below link http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/backtracking-example/

Also back tracking is way in which you keep track of your path by pushing it on stack as you go ahead, when you have to go back just pop from stack.